# how to give expression greater than

Tags: sql, oracle, expression

i want to find the teamnumber which have more won a game than they lost a game. which query should i use?

the table MATCHES contains:

```
Teamnumber      number(2,0)
playernumber    number(2,0)
won             number(2,0)
lost            number(2,0)
```

Comment: It is not clear from your table structure what your data looks like. Are multiple records for each team, one for each player (playernumber?) that played in a game? In that case, it will not be possible to reconstruct the answer you want, unless exactly the same number of players played in a game (For example, only 11 players played in EVERY football match, not 11 or sometimes 12 or sometimes 13....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select teamnumber from team group by teamnumber having sum(won) > sum (lost)